# Where should I put my dispatch in lifecycle react redux

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, redux-thunk

Im having troubles with my app, I want to retrieve an array Lessons from User collection, based on user id logged in. 
Im using redux thunk, jwt auth

I tried to dispatch my getMyLessons in componentDidMount but it takes this.props.auth.user as null param, but if I used it on render() it loads (it gets freezed but loaded it lol), so I think it's a lyfecicle issue

```
class DashboardSidebar extends Component {
    componentDidMount(){
        this.props.getMyLessons(this.props.auth.user._id);
    }     

    static propTypes = {
        auth: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
        lesson: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
        getMyLessons: PropTypes.func.isRequired
    }

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({    
    auth: state.auth,
    lesson: state.lesson
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps,{ getMyLessons })(DashboardSidebar);
```

Comment: From what it seem, it looks like your auth.user is not populated in the initial render but on the next render due to which it is null in componentDidMount. Make sure you get the value initially or use `componentDidUpdate` with a check on user._id change

Comment: It seems that you are verifying a prop a bit earlier. 1. Never run Async code in the render function 2. Use `componentDidUpdate()` to verify if the `auth` has the value and dispatch your action there 3. Have a flag so you don't run your logic more than once

Comment: You can try writing the code in componentWillReceiveProps method of the lifecycle.

Comment: Thanks to everyone said that I should used it on componentDidUpdate it already worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it in `componentDidUpdate`:

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
  const {user} = this.props.auth;
  if (user && user._id && user._id !== prevProps.auth.user._id) {
    this.props.getMyLessons(user._id);
  }
}
```